# Unsupported operand type in array for a nested loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am attempting to write a nested loop in order to compute a number of values for temperature (te) against time (t), each with a different timestep (dt) being used.

```
dt_values = [0.05, 0.025, 0.1, 0.05, 0.001]

for j in dt_values:
    t = np.arange(0,100,[j])
    te = np.zeros(len(t))
    te[0] = te_init 
    dt = j
    def f(te):
        y = -r*(te - te_surr) # y is the derivative
        return y
    for i in range(1,len(t)):
        te[i] = te[i-1] + f(te[i-1])*[j]



plt.plot(t, te)
```

However I am receiving the following error message:

> t = np.arange(0,100,[j])
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'

So, it is not possible to use a list in the way I have done when creating the t array? I cannot use, for example

for j in range ...

As the values I have for dt are not separated evenly. So, I am wondering, is there another way of defining dt_values which is supported in np.arange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step parameter should be an int not a list. **Change [j] to j**
More info on **[numpy.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)**

```
dt_values = [0.05, 0.025, 0.1, 0.05, 0.001]

for j in dt_values:
    t = np.arange(0,100,j)
    te = np.zeros(len(t))
    te[0] = te_init 
    dt = j
    def f(te):
        y = -r*(te - te_surr) # y is the derivative
        return y
    for i in range(1,len(t)):
        te[i] = te[i-1] + f(te[i-1])*[j]



plt.plot(t, te)
```